# R: How can I homogenise people's names in a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 10.000+ observations. The first column consists in names of people that appeared in a political list year after year.

Problem: this names are not always the same although the person is indeed the same.

Examples of the data frame:
**1. In this case, there is only a missing accent mark in one of the entries**

- Abel Aguado Roman
- Abel Aguado Román
- Abel Aguado Román

**2. In this case, well, there is a big chaos**

- Alfonso Fernández Pérez
- Alfonso Fernando Fernandez Preze
- Alfonso Fernando Fernandez Prrérez
- Alfonso Ferndo Fernández Perez
- Alfonso Ffernández Perez

What I want to do is to homogenise the names to be make them identifiable as the same person to R, for my analysis. 
Is there any possibility without doing it manually?
Thanks!

Comment: You could take a look at `?hclust` or `?agrep`. This is a quite broad question, though.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions useful links [ask] [reprex]. include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df))

Comment: have you considered https://openrefine.org/ ?

Comment: Are there other data points that point you to identify two names that are same identity? For example, the address or an id or combination of other data points such as spouse details? In other words, if you were to do this manually how would you know they are same person? Once you know that, it can be coded in R.

Comment: This could be helpful: https://justrthings.com/2016/11/03/record-linkage-approximate-string-matching-with-stringdist/ also the [fuzzyjoin package](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin)

Answer (score 0):

This is a messy task, especially if you have many name *types* with many name *variants*. If these numbers are managable, then this regex solution would work:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(names_all = c("Alfonso Fernández Pérez", "Abel Aguado Roman", "Abel Aguado Román","Alfonso Fernando Fernandez Preze", "Alfonso Fernando Fernandez Prrérez",
                               "Alfonso Ferndo Fernández Perez", "Abel Aguado Roman", "Abel Aguado Román", "Alfonso Ffernández Perez", "Alfonso Fernández Pérez"))
```

You could first define all variants of all name types:

```
variants_A <- c("Alfonso Fernández Pérez","Alfonso Fernando Fernandez Preze", "Alfonso Fernando Fernandez Prrérez",
              "Alfonso Ferndo Fernández Perez", "Alfonso Ffernández Perez")
variants_B <- c("Abel Aguado Roman", "Abel Aguado Román")
```

as well as standard names for all name types:

```
standard_A <- "Alfonso Fernández Pérez"
standard_B <- "Abel Aguado Román"
```

To 'homogenize' the names you could use an `ifelse` statement (or nested `ifelse` statements if you have more than two name types) and, using `grepl`, match each of the name variants and replace it by the respective standard name:

```
df$names_clean <- ifelse(grepl(paste0(variants_A, collapse = "|"), df$names_all), 
                     standard_A, standard_B)
```

Alternatively, here's a `dplyr` solution (working along the same logic):

```
library(dplyr)
df$names_clean <- df %>% 
  mutate(names_all = case_when(grepl(paste0(variants_A, collapse = "|"), names_all) ~ standard_A,
                                     TRUE                                           ~ standard_B))
```

Result:

```
df
                            names_all             names_clean
1             Alfonso Fernández Pérez Alfonso Fernández Pérez
2                   Abel Aguado Roman       Abel Aguado Román
3                   Abel Aguado Román       Abel Aguado Román
4    Alfonso Fernando Fernandez Preze Alfonso Fernández Pérez
5  Alfonso Fernando Fernandez Prrérez Alfonso Fernández Pérez
6      Alfonso Ferndo Fernández Perez Alfonso Fernández Pérez
7                   Abel Aguado Roman       Abel Aguado Román
8                   Abel Aguado Román       Abel Aguado Román
9            Alfonso Ffernández Perez Alfonso Fernández Pérez
10            Alfonso Fernández Pérez Alfonso Fernández Pérez
```

Does this help?